# Creating a batchfile to run CSVfix echo

Tags: csv, batch-file, echo, csvfix

I'm looking to target a few hundred .CSV files located in a data folder, from there I'm trying to run "CSVfix Echo" which I'm told should add quotes around all of my data points. This needs to be done to clean up a CSV import into SQL.

My problems are trying to create and run this batch file, as I keep getting an error

"'csvfix' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

and how to target only specific CSV files within my folder. I only need to target files with the word notes in them. I assume I'll just have %notes% in the command prompt somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never heard of csvfix. Where did you download it from?

Comment: Run `csvfix` (whatever it is) by typing its full path (quoted) into command prompt...

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).